# A view that was not created gets displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**I don't** have a view called `Test`. But, **there's a method** in the `Home` controller called `Test`.

Everything works fine, the `Test` method gets executed and redirected to `Index` view as given in the code. However, in the browser the URL is `../Home/Test` and not `../Home/Index`. I don't have a View called `Test` so why is this getting displayed ?  I don't want this URL to be displayed in the browser. How can i solve this ?

View:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="file" />
    ..// Other code
}
```

C#

```
public ActionResult Test(HttpPostedFileBase f)
        {
            var m = new HomeModel();
            ..// Other code goes here
            return View("../Home/Index", m); // Will be returning the Index View
        }
```

Comment: try `return View("Index", m);`

Comment: Thank you, i used your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In URL

> "../Home/Test"

Test is action thus it is working fine.

If you don't want this URL to be displayed, renamed the Action "Test" to "Index" and also update its references

and use (optional)

```
return View("Index", m)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard setting for MVC, it is not the View, but The Method, that is displayed in the browser. The method then by default returns the View (but that is optional).

So what you need to do is rename you Test Method to Index and place [HttpPost] on top of it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase f)
        {
            var m = new HomeModel();
            ..// Other code goes here
            return View(m);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return View("../Home/Index", m);
```

This will not redirect you to `Index`; it will simply display your Index *view*. If you want browser to automatically change your URL from `/Test` to `/Index` you have to instead do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Test(HttpPostedFileBase f)
{
 var m = new HomeModel();
 ..// Other code goes here
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Where is the model passing?